# Drop and create table inside transaction on SQL Server, impact on other processes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On SQL Server 2005, is it possible to drop and recreate a table (copy from another database) inside of a transaction?

Also, would any process trying to access that table during the transaction fail or wait for the transaction to complete?

Comment: Because the table is used then by many other tables. We're updating with new data throughout the day. Linked db not an option.

Comment: I guess you can access the data you want in a select statement, and obviously the destination table.  how about a solution with a merge statement ?  
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: @DefyGravity, Interesting. We'll take a look.

Comment: @DefyGravity, although, can the merge be atomic? We don't want queries against the table while the updat is going on, but we don't want the queries to fail either.

Comment: @Christopher pretty sure it is atomic, but not positive.  Here's why I think that:  All merge statement altered target rows' after triggers fire once the merge statement completes.  the effected rows' triggers fire in a random, not guaranteed order.  that implies atomicity to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the data into a different table, then switch the old and new tables. Use either [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) or see [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx). The later option is better because it preserves all permissions and constraints on the table, but it does require Enterprise Edition.

Comment: But "is it possible to drop and recreate a table (copy from another database) inside of a transaction?"

Comment: It is possible. Hardly recommended.

Comment: Interesting... Will check that out.

Comment: Also, what will happen to other accessing transactions: the DROP TABLE will take a SCH-M (schema modification) lock on the table. Other transaction will need, at the very least, a SCH-S (schema stability) lock on the table, *even transactions that read with NOLOCK*. All those transactions will be blocked until the DROP TABLE transactions commits or rolls back.